# Conditionally show/hide field based on content of field in EXTENDED lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, if-condition

**Problem**: I want to show/hide a field based on the content of a field in an EXTENDED lookup column.

I have the following two lists:

```
LIST 1: "*Opgaver*"
 COLUMN: "*Opgave*"
 COLUMN: "*Område*"

LIST 2: "*Tidsregistrering*"
 COLUMN: "Aktivitet"
 COLUMN: "Underområde"
 COLUMN: "Opgave" (lookup)
 COLUMN: "Opgave: Område" (extended lookup based on lookup)
```

I use Power Automate to ensure that all involved columns are available in text format (just a sidenote to avoid confusion).

In list 2 I only want to show the field pertaining to "*Underområde*" if the field in column "*Opgave: Område*" in list 2 has a certain content. I have tried to use the following formular from [Microsofts learning material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#specify-conditional-formula-to-show-or-hide-columns):

```
=if(substring([$Opgave: Område],indexOf([$Opgave: Område],';#')+2,1000) == 'Toronto', 'true', 'false')
```

But this results in the error message "*Use valid condition*". I am unable to figure out if this is caused by a faulty reference ($Opgave: Område) or it is due to the fact that I simply cannot use an extended lookup column for conditional logic.

Please help - TIA

Comment: Try using correct **internal names** of your columns in formula once: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Extended lookup columns might not be officially supported in SharePoint conditional formulas, I need to do some tests to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks, @GaneshSanap-MVP. I retrieved the following **internal name** based on your blog: "*Opgave%5Fx003a%5F%5Fx0020%5FOmr%5Fx00e5%5Fde*". Not very handy :) But tried to use it and got the same error message ("*Use valid condition*").